# Regular Expression how to print one of two in matching pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, mt940

I have a problem with Regular Expressions.
I'm writing a small program that matches a line from mt940 bank statement file.
I have a simple string like this one:

```
:60F:C120613PLN245265,82
```

And a regular expression:

```
([C|D]{1})|([0-9]{6})|([A-Z]{3})|([0-9]+(\,[0-9]{2}))
```

that returns me

```
C
120613
PLN
143783 
4,82
```

But the last two rows are separated, and i would recaived not separated last two rows, like this:

```
C
120613
PLN
1437834,82
```

I think, that the last rows has a 6 numbers before ",", that matches to a second pattern in my whole pattern.

What I can do to recaive the last two words not separated?

Comment: Which language / regexp variety ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern works for me:

```
pattern "([C|D]{1})([0-9]{6})([A-Z]{3})([0-9]+,[0-9]{2})"
```

I've tested it in **Python**:

```
re.findall(pattern, ":60F:C120613PLN245265,82") // [('C', '120613', 'PLN', '245265,82')]
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answer.

In python is working without "|" char, you're right.
But in C# is an a problem.
I'm used other way, to solve the problem:
I've used an option "RightToLeft" and it's now working.